# How to add 1 to 0 in a column

Tags: r, if-statement

I have one column in a table where I need to change 0 to 1. I undestand that basically it should be something like

```
 if(0 %in% COLUMN){then add 1}
```

but I'm not sure and can't find the way how to make it correctly so the R would add 1 to each 0 in one exact column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a `if/else` loop.  It can be directly done with vectorized option

```
df1$COLUMN[df1$COLUMN == 0] <- 1
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1$COLUMN <- (!df1$COLUMN) + df1$COLUMN
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(COLUMN = c(5, 0, 3, 2, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is to use `ifelse`

```
COLUMN <- ifelse(COLUMN==0,1,COLUMN)
```